# Why does my suscripción don't allow me to use custom vision?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have entered my azure portal ( custom vision) but It does not allow me to use the service?

[image: Screenshot of Azure project]

Comment: If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Custom Vision service there are 2 tiers. You can sign up for a F0 (free) or S0 (standard) subscription through the Azure portal.

From error, it looks like your F0 (free) subscription has reached its limit.

[image]

Refer this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/limits-and-quotas) for more information.